# Alternative to subquery matching in a view with multiple matching results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to build a query that will drive a view.  The functionality i am looking for seems to come up quite often and i'm pretty sure their is a better alternative to it than using a subquery with a CASE like i have been doing.

Lets say we have two tables with ids with primary keys like so. Lets say for this example that table b has a constraint where only one teacher can be assigned to each grade, but any number of teachers can be assigned to a grade.

```html
table a

gradeid    grade  
-------------------
1           A      
2           B     
3           C     
4           D     
5           F  
     
table b

teachid  gradeid  teacher
-------------------------
1      1      mary    
2       1      bob 
3      2      sue  
4        3      sally  
5        4      sally  
6        5      rich 
7        1      bill
8        2      bill 
9        3      chris
```

Now lets say we want to write a view query that is for some export to excel functionality that takes data from Table a and joins it on table b in a way where we can see if there is a positive join for a particular grade without returning multiple rows per match and having to manually flatten the data.  What we want is a view that is locked by the number of results from table A (in this example 5, but we could add more grades and have it expand down)  Here is what our view would look like:

*Note* Rest signifies all other unique teacher matches that are not bob or billaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

```html
View

gradeid  grade  bobsname bobsid billsname billsid restids restnames
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1      A      bob 2     bill   7   1   mary
2       B      null  null bill   8   3   sue
3      C      null   null null   null    4,9     sally,chris
4        D      null   null null   null    5       sally
5        F      null   null null   null    6       rich
```

The way i could do this would be to use subqueries with a CASE statement.

Something like

```html
SELECT a.gradeid, a.grade, 
CASE WHEN (select bob.teachid from tableb bob left join on a.gradeid = bob.gradeid) IS NOT NULL (select bob.teachid from tableb bob left join on a.gradeid = bob.gradeid) ELSE NULL END as bobsid,
CASE WHEN (select bob.teacher from tableb bob left join on a.gradeid = bob.gradeid) IS NOT NULL (select bob.teacher from tableb bob left join on a.gradeid = bob.gradeid) ELSE NULL END as bobsname,
CASE WHEN (select bill.teachid from tableb bill left join on a.gradeid = bill.gradeid) IS NOT NULL (select bill.teachid from tableb bill left join on a.gradeid = bill.gradeid) ELSE NULL END as billsid,
CASE WHEN (select bill.teacher from tableb bill left join on a.gradeid = bill.gradeid) IS NOT NULL (select bill.teacher from tableb bill left join on a.gradeid = bill.gradeid) ELSE NULL END as billsname,
CASE WHEN REALLY LONG THING THAT IS TOO UGLY TO WRITE AND MAKES ME ASK HERE ETC....
FROM table a
```

This may be the only way to accomplish this, but i believe that there has to be a better way to do this.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if bob and bill and "rest" is significant. If so this gives you what you want

```
;with bob as 
(
    select gradeid, teacher as bobsname, teachid as bobsid
    from #tab2 
    where teacher = 'bob'
),
bill as 
(
    select gradeid, teacher as billsname, teachid as billsid
    from #tab2 
    where teacher = 'bill'
),
rest as
(
    select gradeid,
        substring(cast(ids.ids as varchar(8000)), 2, 7999) as restids,
        substring(cast(names.names as varchar(8000)), 2, 7999) as restnames
    from 
    (
        select distinct gradeid
        from #TAB2 
    )   t1
    cross apply 
    (
        select ',' + convert(varchar, teachid) 
        from #tab2 t2
        where t1.gradeid = t2.gradeid
        and teacher not in ('bob','bill')
        order by teachid
        for xml path('')
    ) ids(ids)
    cross apply
    (
        select ',' + teacher
        from #tab2 t2
        where t1.gradeid = t2.gradeid
        and teacher not in ('bob','bill')
        order by teachid
        for xml path('')
    ) names(names)
)    
select grade, max(bobsname), max(bobsid), max(billsname), max(billsid), max(restnames), max(restids)
from #tab1
inner join #tab2 on #TAB1.gradeid = #tab2.gradeid
left outer join bob on #tab2.teachid = bobsid and bob.gradeid = #TAB1.gradeid
left outer join bill on #tab2.teachid = billsid and bill.gradeid = #TAB1.gradeid
left outer join rest on rest.gradeid = #TAB1.gradeid
group by grade
```

Comment: rest stands for all other matches that are not bob and bill.

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to go with Dynamic Coding.

Schema from your Question

```
CREATE TABLE #TAB1(gradeid   INT, grade VARCHAR(20))


INSERT INTO #TAB1
SELECT 1,'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'B'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'C'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'D'
UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'F'

CREATE TABLE #TAB2(teachid INT,gradeid   INT, teacher VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO #TAB2
SELECT 1 ,   1 , 'mary' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 ,   1 , 'bob' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 ,   2 , 'sue' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 4 , 3, 'sally' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 5 , 4 , 'sally' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 6 , 5 , 'rich' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 7 , 1 , 'bill'
UNION ALL
SELECT 8 , 2 , 'bill' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 9 , 3 , 'chris'
```

Now Query the Tables by building dynamic Query

```
DECLARE @QRY VARCHAR(MAX), @TEACHERNAMES VARCHAR(MAX)='', @TEACHERIDS VARCHAR(MAX)=''
,@ALIASES VARCHAR(MAX)=''

--Names column for PIVOTing Name wise
SELECT @TEACHERNAMES=  @TEACHERNAMES+'[' + teacher + '],'  FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT teacher FROM #TAB2)A
SELECT @TEACHERNAMES = SUBSTRING(@TEACHERNAMES,1,LEN(@TEACHERNAMES)-1)

--ID column names for PIVOTing ID wise
SELECT @TEACHERIDS=  @TEACHERIDS+'[' + teachid + '],'  FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT CAST(teachid AS VARCHAR(20))teachid FROM #TAB2)A
SELECT @TEACHERIDS = SUBSTRING(@TEACHERIDS,1,LEN(@TEACHERIDS)-1)

--Aliases as your requirement
SELECT @ALIASES =@ALIASES
+ '['+CAST(TEACHID AS VARCHAR(20))+'] AS '+TEACHER+'_id ,['+teacher+'] AS '+teacher+'_name'+',' 
FROM #TAB2
SELECT @ALIASES = SUBSTRING(@ALIASES,1,LEN(@ALIASES)-1)


SELECT @QRY = '
SELECT T1.GRADEID, '+@ALIASES+' FROM #TAB1 T1
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM #TAB2
)AS A
PIVOT
(
    MAX(teachid) FOR teacher IN ('+@TEACHERNAMES+')
) AS PVT
)ID
ON T1.gradeid= ID.GRADEID
LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM #TAB2
)AS A
PIVOT
(
    MAX(teacher) FOR teachid IN ('+@TEACHERIDS+')
) AS PVT
)AS NAME
ON T1.gradeid= NAME.gradeid
'


EXEC( @QRY)
```